# Does SQL Server Data Tools for Business Intelligence (SSDT-BI) require a license?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt-bi

I know this question has been indirectly addressed, but I recently found the downloads for the 2012 and 2013 version of the SQL Server Data Tools for Business Intelligence.  When running for the first time after install, a dialog popped up which indicated that the 30-day trial period had expired and that I had to sign in in order to continue using the application.  I have an MSDN account so I signed in.  Now when I re-start, I no longer get the dialog from before, presumably because license information was downloaded when I signed in before.  So my question is Is a license required to use SSDT-BI or not?  And if not, why was I required to sign in?

Here is the link with the downloads:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522628(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I installed SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, both with license. I activated them and then I installed the SSDT plugin for Visual Studio

I didn't sign and I'm pretty sure you're no required to do so unless you have an express visual studio/SQL server, which doesn't support data mining.

I hope I helped.
Best wishes,